# Zcash configure in ubuntu

Tags: bitcoind, bitcore, zcash

I have tried to installed zcash insight ui & api in my local machine (ubuntu OS) and it is completed all the steps but I m facing issue while start services in frontground.

Let me share with you command, config file.

```
npm install -g zcash-bitcore-node
zcash-bitcore-node create mynode
cd mynode
zcash-bitcore-node install insight-api
zcash-bitcore-node install insight-ui
zcash-bitcore-node start
```

But getting below error in my terminal:

```
[2018-01-30T12:33:03.687Z] info: Using config: /home/kiran/zcashnodenew/zcash-bitcore-node.json
[2018-01-30T12:33:03.688Z] info: Using network: testnet
[2018-01-30T12:33:03.688Z] info: Starting bitcoind
[2018-01-30T12:33:03.690Z] info: Using zcash config file: /home/kiran/zcashnodenew/data/zcash.conf
[2018-01-30T12:33:03.691Z] info: Starting zcash process
[2018-01-30T12:33:03.699Z] error: Error: spawn /usr/local/lib/node_modules/zcash-bitcore-node/bin/zcashd ENOENT
at _errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:201:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:389:16)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
```

### MY Config File  (zcash-bitcore-node.json)

```
{
  "network": "testnet",
  "port": 3003,
  "services": [
    "bitcoind",
    "insight-api",
    "insight-ui",
    "web"
  ],
  "servicesConfig": {
    "bitcoind": {
      "spawn": {
        "datadir": "./data",
        "exec": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/zcash-bitcore-node/bin/zcashd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Zcash Config  (zcash.conf)

```
server=1
whitelist=127.0.0.1
txindex=1
addressindex=1
timestampindex=1
spentindex=1
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcuser=bitcoin2
rpcpassword=local321
uacomment=bitcore
```

Can you please help me with it? What is wrong in which step?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit old but anyway, use this repo to build it for you:

https://github.com/radix42/zcash-block-explorer